# EF6: Use reference/lookup data with IQueryable

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6, lookup, iqueryable

I want to use a pre-loaded lookup data from a list within a query.  I need the query to return as IQueryable because it is used in a grid & being paged (not included here). I need the Labels to load from the lookup to avoid joins (more are in the actual code).

I know I could do a ToList() and post-process it, but I need the IQueryable.  Here is the code:

```
// Run in intialization other code...
var contactLookups = new ContactsDbContext();
List<StatusType> _statusTypes = contactLookups.StatusTypes.ToList();


    public IQueryable GetQuery()
    {
        var contactsCtx = new ContactsDbContext();
        IQueryable query = contactsCtx.Select(contact => new
        {
            Id = contact.Id,
            FullName = contact.FirstName + " " + contact.LastName,
            CompanyName = contact.CompanyName,
            Status = _statusTypes.FirstOrDefault(l => contact.StatusId == l.Id).Label
        });
        return query;
    }
```

The code above throws an error because EF/LINQ can't form the in-memory list into SQL (for obvious reasons) - unless something is added/changed.

I want to *somehow* tell EF to apply the lookup after the SQL or something to that effect.  I had read about doing something similar with EF Helper code and Expressions, but I can't find that article anymore.

Note, I'm flexible on the lookup itself.  The only non-negotiable is the "contact.StatusId" (int), but the rest of the structure "_statusTypes.FirstOrDefault(l => contact.StatusId == l.Id)", like the List type, is open.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can You read just contact.StatusId and fill the Status manually later?

Comment: No, the query gets bound to the grid as a result of the method call.  Also, this type of call is only one of many with the above query as an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap EF's query into your own intercepting implementation of IQueryable, in which you can inject values of in-memory lookups prior to returning objects to application.

It may sound complex, but actually is not that hard to implement. The following needs to be done:

1. Mark the `Status` property in your entity as non-mapped (using `Ignore()` with Fluent API or `[NotMapped]` attribute on the property).
2. Write `InterceptingQueryable<T>` (let's name it so) implementation of `IOrderedQueryable<T>`, which wraps an `IQueryable<T>` object from the EF (returned by the Select method in your example).
3. Write `InterceptingQueryProvider<T>` implementation of `IQueryProvider<T>`, which in turn wraps query provider obtained from the EF.
4. Write `InterceptingEnumerator<T>` implementation of `IEnumerator<T>`, which relays to enumerator object returned by the EF. **This enumerator will inject the value of Status property (can easily be generalized to populate any lookup property this way), right after it performs `MoveNext`, so that object returned by `Current` is fully populated.**

The above chain is connected as follows:

1. `InterceptingQueryable` relays to EF's query object, passed in the constructor.
2. `InterceptingQueryable.Provider` property returns `InterceptingQueryProvider`.
3. `InterceptingQueryable.GetEnumerator` method returns `InterceptingEnumerator`.
4. `InterceptingQueryProvider.CreateQuery` methods obtain query object from the EF query provider, then return it wrapped in another instance of  `InterceptingQueryable`.
5. `InterceptingQueryProvider.Execute` invokes `Execute` on the EF query provider, then in the case it gets an entity which is subject to lookup injection, it injects the lookup values in the same way as `InterceptingEnumerator` does (extract a method for reuse).

**UPDATE**

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Examples.Queryables
{
    public class InterceptingQueryable<T> : IOrderedQueryable<T>
    {
        private readonly Action<T> _interceptor;
        private readonly IQueryable<T> _underlyingQuery;
        private InterceptingQueryProvider _provider;

        public InterceptingQueryable(Action<T> interceptor, IQueryable<T> underlyingQuery)
        {
            _interceptor = interceptor;
            _underlyingQuery = underlyingQuery;
            _provider = null;
        }
        public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return new InterceptingEnumerator(_interceptor, _underlyingQuery.GetEnumerator());
        }
        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return GetEnumerator();
        }
        public Expression Expression 
        {
            get { return _underlyingQuery.Expression; }
        }
        public Type ElementType 
        {
            get { return _underlyingQuery.ElementType; }
        }
        public IQueryProvider Provider 
        {
            get
            {
                if ( _provider == null )
                {
                    _provider = new InterceptingQueryProvider(_interceptor, _underlyingQuery.Provider); 
                }
                return _provider;
            }
        }

        private class InterceptingQueryProvider : IQueryProvider
        {
            private readonly Action<T> _interceptor;
            private readonly IQueryProvider _underlyingQueryProvider;

            public InterceptingQueryProvider(Action<T> interceptor, IQueryProvider underlyingQueryProvider)
            {
                _interceptor = interceptor;
                _underlyingQueryProvider = underlyingQueryProvider;
            }
            public IQueryable CreateQuery(Expression expression)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
            public IQueryable<TElement> CreateQuery<TElement>(Expression expression)
            {
                var query = _underlyingQueryProvider.CreateQuery<TElement>(expression);

                if ( typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(TElement)) )
                {
                    return new InterceptingQueryable<TElement>((Action<TElement>)(object)_interceptor, query);
                }
                else
                {
                    return query;
                }
            }
            public object Execute(Expression expression)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
            public TResult Execute<TResult>(Expression expression)
            {
                var result = _underlyingQueryProvider.Execute<TResult>(expression);

                if ( result is T )
                {
                    _interceptor((T)(object)result);
                }

                return result;
            }
        }

        private class InterceptingEnumerator : IEnumerator<T>
        {
            private readonly Action<T> _interceptor;
            private readonly IEnumerator<T> _underlyingEnumerator;
            private bool _hasCurrent;

            public InterceptingEnumerator(Action<T> interceptor, IEnumerator<T> underlyingEnumerator)
            {
                _interceptor = interceptor;
                _underlyingEnumerator = underlyingEnumerator;
                _hasCurrent = false;
            }
            public void Dispose()
            {
                _underlyingEnumerator.Dispose();
            }
            public bool MoveNext()
            {
                _hasCurrent = _underlyingEnumerator.MoveNext();

                if ( _hasCurrent )
                {
                    _interceptor(_underlyingEnumerator.Current);
                }

                return _hasCurrent;
            }
            public void Reset()
            {
                _underlyingEnumerator.Reset();
            }
            public T Current 
            {
                get
                {
                    return _underlyingEnumerator.Current;
                }
            }
            object IEnumerator.Current
            {
                get { return Current; }
            }
        }
    }

    public static class QueryableExtensions
    {
        public static IOrderedQueryable<T> InterceptWith<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, Action<T> interceptor)
        {
            return new InterceptingQueryable<T>(interceptor, query);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is test case/example. First, we should not forget to add non-mapped Status property to Contact entity:

```
public partial class Contact
{
    [NotMapped]
    public StatusType Status { get; set; }
}
```

Then, we can use the interceptor mechanism as follows:

```
var contactLookups = contactsCtx.StatusTypes.ToList();

Action<Contact> interceptor = contact => {
    contact.Status = contactLookups.FirstOrDefault(l => contact.StatusId == l.Id);
};

// note that we add InterceptWith(...) to entity set
var someContacts = 
    from c in contactsCtx.Contacts.InterceptWith(interceptor) 
    where c.FullName.StartsWith("Jo")
    orderby c.FullName, c.CompanyName
    select c;

Console.WriteLine("--- SOME CONTACTS ---");
foreach ( var c in someContacts )
{
    Console.WriteLine(
        "{0}: {1}, {2}, {3}={4}", 
        c.Id, c.FullName, c.CompanyName, c.StatusId, c.Status.Name);
}
```

which prints:

```
--- SOME CONTACTS ---
1: John Smith, Acme Corp, 3=Status Three
3: Jon Snow, The Wall, 2=Status Two
```

and the query gets translated into:

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[FullName] AS [FullName], 
    [Extent1].[CompanyName] AS [CompanyName], 
    [Extent1].[StatusId] AS [StatusId]
    FROM [dbo].[Contacts] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[FullName] LIKE 'Jo%'
    ORDER BY [Extent1].[FullName] ASC, [Extent1].[CompanyName] ASC
```

Comment: This is great, thanks. It would be great if you have an example. I think this is close to what I was recalling.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks for a great effort!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is the benefit of avoiding the joins compared to the obvious drawback of not being able to process the whole query at the database side, but what you are asking for can be achieved by doing as much as possible (filtering, ordering, grouping, projection) with Linq to Entities, then turn it into `IEnumerable` and do the rest with Linq To Objects. You can always use `Enumerable.AsQueryable` to switch to `IQueryable` implementation over `IEnumerable`. Something like this

```
public IQueryable GetQuery()
{
    var db = new ContactsDbContext();
    var query = db.Contacts.Select(contact => new
    {
        Id = contact.Id,
        FullName = contact.FirstName + " " + contact.LastName,
        CompanyName = contact.CompanyName,
        StatusId = contact.StatusId
    })
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(contact => new
    {
        Id = contact.Id,
        FullName = contact.FullName,
        CompanyName = contact.CompanyName,
        Status = _statusTypes.FirstOrDefault(l => contact.StatusId == l.Id).Label
    })
    .AsQueryable();
    return query;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try tomorrow.  Not sure if it would defeat the paging or not, but worth a try cause it's a simple solution.  Also, on the 'why', the lookup tables are fully loaded into 2nd lvl cache, so joining to retrieve them again is a waste & performance hit. Consider that I have more that one lookup in this query and the example is simplified for clarity.

Comment: I understand what you gain, which is fine, but trying to warn what are you losing with such approach. If it's not clear from my explanations, the above query works, but everything after `AsEnumerable` will happen in the memory, including your paging or whatever further processing.

Comment: I tried this out & it was effective operated as a .ToList() at the end of the first query, which was what I was avoiding.  Thanks for trying.

Comment: @SteveKinyon I'm not trying, I think I warned you twice. You wanted `IQueryable` and got `IQueryable` :-) If you want a `IQueryable` on which you apply further filtering etc, and all that happen in db, then you should formulate it that way. Good luck.